# What is the easiest way to upgrade from Magento 2.4.5 to 2.4.5-p1?

Tags: magento-upgrade, magento2.4.5

```
Magento 2.4.5
Porto theme
```

**What is the easiest way to upgrade Magento 2.4.5 to Magento 2.4.5 p1 which was released on October 11th?**

---

UPDATED on October 17th, 2022:

When I try to run the following, it gives this Error:

**composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 --no-update**

```
*ERROR: 'composer require' does not function properly for magento/product-community-edition, magento/product-enterprise-edition, or magento/magento-cloud-metapackage metapackages as of Composer 2.1.6. Use 'require-commerce' instead.*
```

---

When I run the following:

**composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 --no-update --with-all-dependencies**

It gives this Error:

**Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.**

Comment: Can you please tell us that your magento 2.4.5 is running fine or not. I want to use Magento 2.4.5 for my site?

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what it says in the error

```
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 --no-update
```

Comment: "Command "require-commerce" is not defined."

Comment: Unless you've experienced the error *ERROR: 'composer require' does not function properly, then you can use composer require instead of composer require-commerce still.  Composer version 1 doesn't seem to generate this error (from memory)

Answer (score 2):

you can upgrade using the following commands:

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable

composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.5-p1 --no-update
composer update

rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf generated/code/*

bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;
bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Comment: I ran all the commands but the version remains the same. I can see that in the Admin panel as well as when I run the following command: php bin/magento --version It returns this: 
Magento CLI 2.4.5
What could be the problem? Why did it not upgrade to 2.4.5. p1?

Comment: I updated the original post if you would take a look please?

Answer (score 1):

You are running composer version `2.1`, which is not matched with system requirements for Magento > 2.4.4 from Magento: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Please do the following steps to upgrade your Magento from 2.4.5 to 2.4.5-p1:

Step 1. Go to the root Magento folder, and update the composer to version 2.2.x (2.3 or 2.4 also works as expected): `composer self-update 2.2.18`

Step 2: Run require composer command: `composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 --no-update`

Step 3: Run composer update command: `composer update`

Step 4: Run the upgrade database command: `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Step 5: Run compilation code command: `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Step 6: Run deploy static content command: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

You are done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.5-p1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

composer **require-commerce**

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf  var/cache/* var/page_cache/* pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/code/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Or composer **require**

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
rm -rf vendor/
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 --no-update
composer update
    rm -rf  var/cache/* var/page_cache/* pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/code/*
    php bin/magento setup:upgrade
    php bin/magento setup:di:compile
    php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;
    php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check magento system requirements as per the version which link is given below and update first if required **Like :-** (php, composer, mysql, elastic search) version etc then start work on it.

You can upgrade magento version using command line follow below steps

1. First Enable maintenance mode using a command.
   **php bin/magento maintenance:enable**
2. Take backup of you composer.json file using command.
   **cp composer.json composer.json.bk**
3. Update composer.json file
   **composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 --no-update**
4. Composer update
   **composer update**
5. Please run below commands one by one.
   **php bin/magento cache:clean**
   **rm -rf var/cache/***

   **rm -rf var/page_cache/***

   **rm -rf generated/code/***

   **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

   **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

   **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**
6. Disable Maintainance Mode.
   **php bin/magento maintenance:disable**